# Changing the charging status of battery forcefully

Tags: java, android

Basically there is some motherboard related issue in my mobile.

If the phone is locked, the phone gets switched off as soon as it's locked.
However, if the phone is in charging state, it works fine.

Also, a main thing, sometime when the phone is just plugged out of charging, the battry still shows its charging, here also the phone works just fine.

To repair, I have to spend **100$**. I was wondring If there is a way to change the battery status manually?

So viewed `BatteryManager` class from the official page.

The methods only show we can `monitor the state`, but cannot change it.

So, **is there any way I can change the charging status if it is not really charging** ?I'll be able to save some money.

Comment: It is not possible. If it was, any app could potentially do dangerous stuff to your phone.

Comment: @Pphoenix any other way to root system files and change it? Otherwise my phone is a waste .

Comment: Are you sure that it is only the status that has to be changed? I mean it can be that when it is locking your phone that it switches some minor part off, and then the phone dies?

Comment: @Pphoenix I have observed that when it shows charging status (even though not charging) it works great.So need to try this out.

Comment: Also, when I talk on the phone, it still works fine if locked.

Comment: Try BatteryCalibration app from Google Play and see if it helps. Other than that, wipe the firmware and install a new one.